# Beaker Cache complains TypeError

Tags: python, caching, beaker

Beaker cache complains a TypeError. I've searched on Google, even tracked beaker's issue tracker but couldn't find anything.

I cache the queries like the following method

```
@staticmethod
def get_queries(query):
    @cache.cache(query, type = 'file', expire = 300)
    def load(query):
        entries = db.get_expensive_query(query)
        return entries
    return load(query)
```

However when I run the program, this is what I receive;

```
  File "/Users/ivan/project/controller/caching.py", line 15, in get_queries
      return load(query)
  File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/Beaker-1.5.4-py2.6.egg/beaker/cache.py", line 417, in cached
    return cache[0].get_value(cache_key, createfunc=go)
  File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/Beaker-1.5.4-py2.6.egg/beaker/cache.py", line 214, in get
    return self._get_value(key, **kw).get_value()
  File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/Beaker-1.5.4-py2.6.egg/beaker/container.py", line 256, in get_value
    if not self._is_expired(stored, expired):
  File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/Beaker-1.5.4-py2.6.egg/beaker/container.py", line 245, in _is_expired
    time.time() >= expiretime + storedtime
TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'float' objects
```

Am I doing something wrong or is this a beaker's bug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code calls cache.cache with an integer for expire, which is correct, but clearly either expiretime or storedtime is winding up with a string.  [From the error message it has to be expiretime. --ed] So here's what I think happened:

(1) You called cache.cache with a string expire at some point.  [Maybe even from the default cache.expire in the CacheManager opts, not sure.]

(2) You fixed the bug, producing the code you submitted (which works for me).

(3) You reran the code *without deleting the cache directory*, and so somehow it picked up the previous state.

I can reproduce your error by following the above prescription.  Could you delete your cache (everything in cache.data_dir and cache.lock_dir) and try again?

Comment: Your first guess on your list was correct. When I've read your comment I revised the code more carefully and found the problem. Thank you!